# GCM notification server PHP not triggering for cordova(phonegap) android

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

Maybe I am missing out on something real basic.. but I couldn't figure it out.

I have server.php as my GCM notification server. When I call this server.php in terminal(MAC) as

```
$ php server.php
```

, it works *perfect*.

Here is my **server.php**

```
<?php
$data = array( 'message' => 'Hello!' );

$ids = array('APA91...'); //my actual registered ID from android device would go here

sendGoogleCloudMessage(  $data, $ids );
function sendGoogleCloudMessage( $data, $ids )
{
    // key from Google APIs Console
    $apiKey = 'AIzaS...'; //my actual API key would go here
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $post = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $ids,
                'data'              => $data,
                );
    $headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );

    // Actually send the push!
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    // Error? Display it!
    if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
    {
        echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
    }
    curl_close( $ch );
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Now, I have this server.php code up in my server computer, and I am trying to call this function via ajax from jquery mobile like this:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myServer.com/server.php",
    data: {"data":sentData}, //i have var sentData setup in actual code
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }  
    });
```

But the same working code doesn't work when I try to trigger it with $.ajax...
What am i doing wrong here?